# Unable to programmatically render webform with supplied default values

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a block that is rendering a webform programmatically however I want to change a field based on the node that it's appearing on. I'm performing this like so.

```
    $webform_id = 'contact';
    $current_node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    $contact_form = \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::load($webform_id);
    $values = ['data' => ['contact_email' => $current_node->field_email->value, 'message' => 'test']];
    $contact_form->getSubmissionForm($values);
    $contact_form_render = \Drupal::entityManager()
        ->getViewBuilder('webform')
        ->view($contact_form);
    return $contact_form_render;
```

It is able to render the webform just fine, however the supplied values for the contact_email field and the message field do not appear, even though they were supplied as a parameter for getSubmissionForm. I've used https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-embed-a-webform as an example but I don't seem to see any discrepancies between my code and theirs.

Is there something wrong with how I'm supplying the values to the programmatically rendered webform?

UPDATE: I tried doing things in a more manual manner

```
$form_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform');
$webform_submission = $form_storage
      ->create(['webform_id'=>'contact', 'data' => ['contact_email' => $current_node->field_email->value],'message' => 'testing']);

$contact_form_render = \Drupal::entityManager()
      ->getViewBuilder('webform')
      ->view($webform_submission);
```

However I get the error

> Exception: Webform id (webform_id) is required to create a webform
>   submission. in Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::preCreate()
>   (line 586 of
>   modules/contrib/webform/src/Entity/WebformSubmission.php).

Even though I'm explicitly setting the webform_id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try using the Webform render element documented at the bottom of https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-embed-a-webform.

```
return [
  '#type' => 'webform',
  '#webform' => 'your_form_id',
  '#default_data' => ['name' => 'Custom Name'],
];
```

Comment: Yep that worked. Would be kind of nice to know why the other way didn't work though.

Comment: @Matt, jrockowitz is right, building a render array is always the best option in D8. While doing this don't forget to add a cache tag for the node and a cache context, otherwise the block won't update when viewing different nodes: `'#cache' => ['contexts' => ['url.path']],`

Comment: The recipe can be updated and the first example should be removed.

Comment: I like to render two forms at the same page. Any idee how to return the render array?